# choosing between the two ways to tropicalize

Tags: terminology, tropical-arithmetic

When tropicalizing a subtraction-free expression (see [Do all subtraction-free identities tropicalize?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127108/do-all-subtraction-free-identities-tropicalize)), is it more common to replace addition by max or by min?

Related issues:

Is there a name for the duality (for piecewise-linear functions involving addition, subtraction, max, and min) that switches max with min?

Is there a name for the duality (for rational functions involving multiplication, division, addition, and "parallel addition" as defined in [Name and notation for a binary operation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/135204/name-and-notation-for-a-binary-operation)) that switches addition with parallel addition?

Background: I'm writing an article that defines certain rational functions involving multiplication, division, addition, and parallel addition, as well as their piecewise-linear tropicalizations, and I want to get the tropicalization correspondence right.

Comment: It seems that the duality that switches $\max$ and $\min$ is called "negation", am I wrong?

Comment: @Theo: It's related to negation.  You negate the variables in the expression and then negate the expression as a whole, e.g., min(x,y) = -max(-x,-y).